# Vite - Linting results in "Unsafe assignment of an any value" on env variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables, vite

I have a react/TS/Vite project where I've set up some env variables as per Vite's docs. I'm getting the `Unsafe assignment of an any value.` lint error on the env variable though. Here's what I've done so far -

Following is my `tsconfig.json` -

```
compilterOptions:{
  "target": "ES2020",
  "module": "ESNext",
  "types": [
      "vitest/globals",
      "vite/client",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom",
      "@testing-library/react",
    ],
  //... other settings
}
```

My `/src` directory has the following `vite-env.d.ts` file where its pointing to `vite/client`, (`src/vite-env.d.ts`) -

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

and following are the `env` files I have

```
.env.development
.env.development.local
.env.example
.env.production
.env.staging
```

All the above env files simply have the following variable-

```
VITE_API_BASE_URL=https://api-dev.myapp.com/api/
```

Now as part of my api layer, I have the following `axios.ts` file (`src/api/axios.ts`) -

```
import assert from 'assert';
import axios from 'axios';

assert(
  import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL,
  'VITE_API_BASE_URL is not defined',
);

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL,
});
```

The problem is, as stated above, upon running `rpm run lint` on the project, I'm getting an `Unsafe assignment of an any value.` error on `baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL,`.

I'm unsure as to why that's happening despite the tsconfig pointing to `vite/client`. I do see inside node_modules that there's `vite/types/importMeta.d.ts` but I don't understand why/how I'd have to point to that manually as a workaround for this issue. Can someone point me to what I'm missing here?

Edit: the corresponding env variable’s value gets loaded just fine, as I’m adhering to the VITE_ prefix. It’s just the type that’s the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type definition imported by

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

looks like this<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
interface ImportMetaEnv {
  [key: string]: any
  BASE_URL: string
  MODE: string
  DEV: boolean
  PROD: boolean
  SSR: boolean
}
```

meaning, any keys other than the built-in ones are of type `any` (See possible reason<sup>[2]</sup>).

This can be solved by checking the type first:

```
if (typeof import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL !== 'string') {
  // throw or return or handle somehow
}
```

Or in your case, you can expand the existing assertion, although that might not be recognized by TypeScript:

```
assert(
  typeof import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL === 'string',
  'VITE_API_BASE_URL is not defined or is of an incorrect type',
);
```

Another method is to not check the type but instead make it to be a string

```
  baseURL: String(import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL),
```

although that string will be incorrect in case the type is actually incorrect - it might be "undefined" or "[Object object]".

Finally, you can do bypass TypeScript checks with type casting or another method but that's a bad habit.

<sup>[1]</sup> [vite/types/importMeta.d.ts](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/65ef38375045935d12ad3f4dd6da90ab5860b5cd/packages/vite/types/importMeta.d.ts)

<sup>[2]</sup>
During the build process, Vite removes expressions like `import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY` from the code and replaces them with literal values taken from the .env file.

However, when the .env file does not contain such a key, then Vite does not replace it with an empty string, it simply leaves the original expression place so it'll be `undefined` rather than a string.

Moreover, you can probably even assign a value to that field in the code, so it can really be of any type in theory.

Comment: thank you! I initially had type-casting as a temp workaround but updating the assert to check whether the env var is indeed string seems like a cleaner approach (although I'm not sure if it'll be any other type than string from the env file).

And just to clarify, when you say "when the key does not exist on the .env file then the import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_CUSTOM_KEY isn't replaced" you're basically meaning that anything other than the ones they've typed in ImportMetaEnv, they're leaving its type open as "any", right?

Comment: @complexSandwich no, I mean there might *actually* be a value of another type there, because the code itself can assign values to keys of `import.meta.env` as long as those keys don't exist on the .env file at all

Comment: Or they 'll be of type `undefined` in case they're, well, not defined

Comment: @complexSandwich I updated the answer a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: adding the check for string on the assert seemed like the best option here. Thanks for looking into this!